# Magento setting up demo version - security threat?

Tags: security, magento, server-side-attacks

I will be making demo version of Magento for a showcase. I want to give users **admin credentials** so they can see what Magento's administration has to offer.

a) Am I exposing server to some kind of **security threat**? I know that you can upload extensions through admin panel.

b) Users will click anything, I am sure of that. So I will make a cronjob to override database and files with backup in a certain time period.

I am not sure what kind of Magento user roles are, I need to look into it, maybe I can find a solution.

What is your opinion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Restrict the admin features accessible to the users by creating the different user and assigning the role.Do not give the full access to the users to all the resources under System>Permissions >Roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to create a new user and provide it with the permission to limited access. If you are not familiar to magento's user roles then [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-admin-users-roles) will be the best place to look for.

I suggest you to backup your database for the safety.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I guess this would be the most secure solution. Thank you again.